# reading the numbers/text from the screen (not image) using openCV and Pytesseract and displaying it

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

how do you code something where I can extract the numbers/text when the code is screen capturing the windows using OpenCV and Pytesseract(or any alternate modules)?

I am done with the code that screen captures your windows but not sure about how to link it with pytesseract to read the data.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import pytesseract as pt
from pytesseract import Output

pt.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

def screencap():
    while(True):
        screen = np.array(ig.grab(bbox=(807,987,957,1035)))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(screen,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("test", gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

image_data = pt.image_to_data(screencap(), output_type=Output.DICT)

print(image_data)
```

I might be missing some lines here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #Now it's working. Give your pytess path here:
 #pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r' ' 
 #& check it out! 

import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import pytesseract as pt
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r''

def screencap():
    while(True):
        screen = np.array(ig.grab(bbox=(807,987,957,1035)))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(screen,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("test", gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

image_data = pytesseract.image_to_data(screencap(), 
output_type=Output.DICT)

print(image_data)
```

Comment: I had an error that states this: TypeError: Unsupported image object

Comment: used the same code that I sent. coz in my system it's working perfectly no errors. kindly check the PIL module.

Comment: Yep, it worked. But there is no output coming out from the terminal.